# Cant find the mistake in code

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

Hi people i have a small problem i cganged the sql database code and my activity code... Now the app crashes when i try to start the activity(1). I am giving you the sql database code too(2). And the text from logcat(3).

**(1):**

```
package com.peky.smartornot;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class POV1 extends Activity {
    Sql ulaz = new Sql(this);
    TextView joke4text;
    TextView joke3text;
    TextView joke2text;
    TextView joke1text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pov1);
        sve();
    }

    public void sve() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ulaz.open();
        int joker1 = ulaz.procitaj(), joker2 = ulaz.procitaj2(), joker3 = ulaz
                .procitaj3(), joker4 = ulaz.procitaj4();
        ulaz.close();
        TabHost joker = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        joker.setup();
        TabSpec izgled = joker.newTabSpec("tag1");
        izgled.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        izgled.setIndicator("Joker 1");
        joker.addTab(izgled);
        izgled = joker.newTabSpec("tag2");
        izgled.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        izgled.setIndicator("Joker 2");
        joker.addTab(izgled);
        izgled = joker.newTabSpec("tag3");
        izgled.setContent(R.id.tab3);
        izgled.setIndicator("Joker 3");
        joker.addTab(izgled);
        izgled = joker.newTabSpec("tag4");
        izgled.setContent(R.id.tab4);
        izgled.setIndicator("Joker 4");
        joker.addTab(izgled);
        joke1text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.joker1text);
        joke1text.setText("You have " + joker1 + " jokers !");
        joke2text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.joker2text);
        joke2text.setText("You have " + joker2 + " jokers !");
        joke3text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.joker3text);
        joke3text.setText("You have " + joker3 + " jokers !");
        joke4text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.joker4text);
        joke4text.setText("You have " + joker4 + " jokers !");
    }

    public void joker1(View view) {
        Button netocan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        Button netocan2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        Button netocan3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        ulaz.open();
        int joker1=ulaz.procitaj(),joker2,joker3,joker4;
        ulaz.close();
        if (joker1 != 0) {
            if(netocan.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
                netocan.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                ulaz.open();
                joker1=joker1-1;
                joker2=ulaz.procitaj2();
                joker3=ulaz.procitaj3();
                joker4=ulaz.procitaj4();
                ulaz.spremijoker(joker1, joker2, joker3, joker4);
                ulaz.close();
                joke1text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.joker1text);
                joke1text.setText("You have " + joker1 + " jokers !");
            }else if(netocan2.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
                netocan2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                ulaz.open();
                joker1=joker1-1;
                joker2=ulaz.procitaj2();
                joker3=ulaz.procitaj3();
                joker4=ulaz.procitaj4();
                ulaz.spremijoker(joker1, joker2, joker3, joker4);
                ulaz.close();
                joke1text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.joker1text);
                joke1text.setText("You have " + joker1 + " jokers !");
            }else if(netocan3.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
                netocan3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                ulaz.open();
                joker1=joker1-1;
                joker2=ulaz.procitaj2();
                joker3=ulaz.procitaj3();
                joker4=ulaz.procitaj4();
                ulaz.spremijoker(joker1, joker2, joker3, joker4);
                ulaz.close();
                joke1text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.joker1text);
                joke1text.setText("You have " + joker1 + " jokers !");
            }else{
                Toast imasodgovor=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You can not use more JOKERS1 on this question !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                imasodgovor.show();
            }

        }else{
            Toast nemasjokera=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You dont have enought JOKERS1 !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            nemasjokera.show();
        }

    }

    public void joker4(View view) {
        ulaz.open();
        int joker1,joker2,joker3,joker4=ulaz.procitaj4();
        ulaz.close();
        Button netocan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        Button netocan2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        Button netocan3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        if (joker4 != 0) {
            if(netocan.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE || netocan2.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE || netocan3.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
            netocan.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            netocan2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            netocan3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            ulaz.open();
            joker1=ulaz.procitaj();
            joker2=ulaz.procitaj2();
            joker3=ulaz.procitaj3();
            joker4=joker4 - 1;;
            ulaz.spremijoker(joker1, joker2, joker3, joker4);
            ulaz.close();
            joke4text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.joker4text);
            joke4text.setText("You have " + joker4 + " jokers !");}else{
                Toast imasodgovor=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You can not use more JOKERS4 on this question !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                imasodgovor.show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast jokertext = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Not enought JOKERS4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            jokertext.show();

        }
    }

    public void joker2(View view){

    }
    public void tocan(View view){
    }
    public void netocanodgovor(View view) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.pov1, menu);
        return false;
    }

}
```

**(2):**

```
package com.peky.smartornot;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class Sql {
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_JOKER1 = "joker";
    public static final String KEY_JOKER2 = "joker2";
    public static final String KEY_JOKER3 = "joker3";
    public static final String KEY_JOKER4 = "joker4";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "SQL";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "peoples_table";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private DbHelper ourHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID
                    + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_JOKER1
                    + " INTEGER, " + KEY_JOKER2 + " INTEGER, " + KEY_JOKER3
                    + " INTEGER, " + KEY_JOKER4 + " INTEGER);");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }

    public Sql(Context c) {
        ourContext = c;
    }

    public Sql open() {
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        ourHelper.close();
    }

    public long spremijoker(int joker1, int joker2, int joker3, int joker4) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(KEY_JOKER1, joker1);

        cv.put(KEY_JOKER2, joker2);

        cv.put(KEY_JOKER3, joker3);

        cv.put(KEY_JOKER4, joker4);

        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

    }

    public int procitaj() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_JOKER1 };
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,
                null, null);
        int citac = 0;
        int iJokerammount = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_JOKER1);
        c.moveToLast();
        citac = c.getInt(iJokerammount);

        return citac;

    }

    public int procitaj2() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_JOKER2 };
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,
                null, null);
        int citac = 0;
        int iJoker2 = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_JOKER2);
        c.moveToLast();
        citac = c.getInt(iJoker2);

        return citac;

    }

    public int procitaj3() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_JOKER3 };
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,
                null, null);
        int citac = 0;
        int iJoker3 = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_JOKER3);
        c.moveToLast();
        citac = c.getInt(iJoker3);

        return citac;

    }

    public int procitaj4() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_JOKER4 };
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,
                null, null);
        int citac = 0;
        int iJoker4 = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_JOKER4);
        c.moveToLast();
        citac = c.getInt(iJoker4);

        return citac;

    }

}
```

(3):

```
03-16 19:32:11.580: E/AndroidRuntime(26569): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-16 19:32:11.580: E/AndroidRuntime(26569): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.peky.smartornot/com.peky.smartornot.POV1}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0
03-16 19:32:11.580: E/AndroidRuntime(26569):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
```

Comment: Are you sure that is the full log? Also, what attempts have you made so far at trying to track down the problem? Also check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error says it all:

> CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0

You are attempting to access an empty list of *something* with an element index of `-1`. `-1` is never a valid array index in Java, so you have two problems:

1. Why is the list empty, if that is indeed not wanted?
2. What is causing the incorrect index value of `-1`?

Since `android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)` is where the problem is being caused, that is where you need to look. What in your code is calling it? Since `performLaunchActivity` is nowhere in your posted code (nor is your `main` function), and since your stack trace is not more thorough, we'll need more information before we can help you further.

Comment: I haven't gone through your code, but if you are migrating from other languages where -1 is a valid index, you will have to change it to `List.getLength()-1` or similar.

Comment: Changed "never" to "never in Java".

Comment: So if i add in the on create code a content value to put 0 in it it ahould fix my problem? And no the minimal value  should be 0 the list is empty i guess. I will try it out.

Comment: Can't say for sure without seeing more relevant code, but it certainly is worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

**I found a fix for the problem i set in the procitaj method:**

```
for(c.moveToFirst;!c.isAfterLast;c.moveToNext){
 citac = c.getInt(iJoker4);
}
```

**instead of:**

```
c.moveToLast;
```

Thanks anyway !